# rospy.sleep doesn't get awaken

Tags: ros, rospy, sleep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Only on one of my machine, this elementary subscribe/publishing tutorial ([WritingPublisherSubscriber(python)](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28python%29)) doesn't work. In talker.py, thread never returns from `rospy.sleep(t)` (`t` can be double number). On my other machine this doesn't happen. Any idea?

Environment:

- where problem occurs: `Ubuntu 11.04, electric, Python 2.7.1+`
- where does not: `Ubuntu 10.10, electric, Python 2.6.6`

Looking at these diff, I just tried to use `python` 2.6.6 (by downgrading like [this](http://goo.gl/i3LcK)), and found no effect.

Source code (exactly the same with the one in the tutorial page):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import roslib; roslib.load_manifest('beginner_tutorials')
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import String
def talker():
    pub = rospy.Publisher('chatter', String)
    rospy.init_node('talker')
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        str = "hello world %s"%rospy.get_time()
        rospy.loginfo(str)
        pub.publish(String(str))
        rospy.sleep(1.0)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        talker()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException: pass
```

---

Update) It also occurred when I use C++ version of the same tutorial.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11761/rospy.sleep-doesn%27t-get-awaken/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2011-11-01

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solved - After I reboot OS, this phenomenon has stopped to happen. Still don't know the root cause though...The last time OS was rebooted was for a few days ago and I hibernated it a few times.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2011-11-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suspect that the parameter /use_sim_time was set to True. Maybe you started either stage or gazebo before?

When /use_sim_time is set and no time provider is running, all ROS sleep methods will just block infinitely.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2011-11-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2011-11-02**:
@Lorenz thanks. I'll keep that parameter in mind although now I can't reproduce the phenom. I haven't explicitly turned it on but is there any trigger that could make the parameter on without knowing?